# Pointing an image based on its coordinates using javascript/html

Tags: javascript, html, image

I want to give x,y coordinates as input and there would be a point(black/red) on an image on that specific coordinate.Is there any way to do that using javascript/html?I want to do it without any internet connection

Comment: Did you give it a try?

Comment: i found the way to get the coordinates of an image but i have no idea about pointing at that specific location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probally looking for something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lxvkb1ok/1/

if you click on the image it automaticly moves the X to the mouse coords.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').click(function(e) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var x = e.clientX - offset.left;
    var y = e.clientY - offset.top;
      $(".test").css({"top":y-4,"left":x-4,"display":"block"});
  });
});
```

I hope this helped you out!